# How to make a string from one kind of array items?

Tags: php, arrays, string

I have an array like this:

```
$results = $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

/*
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [id] => 191
            [type] => 3
            [table_code] => 15
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [id] => 192
            [type] => 3
            [table_code] => 15
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [id] => 194
            [type] => 3
            [table_code] => 15
        )
)
*/
```

And I'm trying to make a string of all IDs with a comma separator. Something like this:

```
echo $ExpectedOutput; // 193, 192, 194
```

How can I do that?

---

Here is what I've tried so far:

```
foreach($results as $item) {
    $ExpectedOutput = $item['id'];
}
```

But always there is a `,` in the end of that string.

Comment: use `echo implode(",", array_column($arr, "id"))`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do this using the `implode` and `array_column`.

Array Column makes an array from all the id of that array, and after that implode makes a string from that array with a delimiter. As you want to use `,`.

```
echo implode(", ", array_column($results, "id")); //193, 192, 194
```

Answer (score 2):

try this

```
foreach($results as $item) {
   if($ExpectedOutput)
      $ExpectedOutput .= ',';
   $ExpectedOutput .= $item['id'];
}

echo $ExpectedOutput;  //193, 192, 194
```

Answer (score 1):

Add one more line into your code for removing final comma using substr function.

```
if($expectedOutput != '')  
  $expectedOutput  = substr($expectedOutput,0,-1);  
echo $expectedOutput; // 191, 192, 194
```

Comment: That's not standard but it should work. Thank you +1

Comment: May be... Using implode and array_column function is the best way.  From the @Frayne Konok answer